# How to give permissions to the source code via maven

Tags: svn, maven-3

Background:

I've a SVN Project which has lot of shell + DB scripts, in which some of them missing execute permission while svn check-out itself.

After maven build of this project (This Just compiles the our sybase SP's(from .prc) and converts them into .ssp files).

When applying this DB Build on any env, we used to cd into this project (from Build server), and execute some master script.

Now, the problem is these shell scripts (+ other executables) are having issues with dos2unix and execute permission. The SVN Mime-type + Line endings are set already.. But the files are checked-in about a decade before are still having issues..

Just thinking of using combination of Maven-assembly-plugin (to provide the permission + take care of line ending) and Maven-dependency-plugin to unpack the same.

Is there any best ways in maven to fix this issue (during Build)..

Answer (score 1):

First i would suggest to fix the execution flag for executions on linux in svn via `svn:executable` property which means simply setting it for the appropriate files and check them in.

```
svn propset svn:executable "*" thescriptfile.sh
```

In maven-assembly-plugin you can define file/directory [permissions (fileMode) in the assembly-descriptors](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_fileSet)